# Informix select first 250000 then the last 250000 records in a table

Tags: informix, cfml

I work on a CFML script to backup some data in a CSV file from Informix database. The problem is the table has many records `286906` and my scripts timeouts (even I set it not to), the best I could successfully was `260000` with:

```
SELECT FIRST 260000
  APE1, APE2, CALLE, CODPOSTAL, DNI, FCADU, FENACI, LOCALIDAD, NOMBRE, NSS, PROV, TELEFONO
FROM
  mytable WHERE FCADU IS NOT NULL AND FENACI IS NOT NULL
```

is there any way to select the rest of 260000 and then the rest?
I tried with:

```
SELECT SKIP 260000 FIRST 520000
  APE1, APE2, CALLE, CODPOSTAL, DNI, FCADU, FENACI, LOCALIDAD, NOMBRE, NSS, PROV, TELEFONO
FROM
  mytable WHERE FCADU IS NOT NULL AND FENACI IS NOT NULL
```

but I get `Error Executing Database Query. A syntax error has occurred.`

Comment: which version are you working? `select dbinfo('version','full') from sysmaster:sysdual`

Comment: `The specified table (sysmaster:sysdual) is not in the database`

Comment: Must be quite old then, which is going to limit your options. The use of sysdual is not actually important in this context, so try `SELECT DISTINCT DBINFO('version', 'full') FROM systables`

Comment: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 7.31.UD9

Comment: Anyway, I kind of solved it with PHP and PDO. Still timing out with CFM.

Comment: Very very old version, the `skip` keyword was supported after version 10+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Unload statement for creating a file from database:

```
UNLOAD TO 'mytable.txt' SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Maybe that this not works in CFML environment. So you can create a stored procedure which unloads your data.

See [unload statement in stored procedure](http://www.iiug.org/forums/classics/index.cgi/noframes/read/2026)

Answer (score 0):

Is it your script timing out or your database connection? From your question it sou ds to me like its not the coldfusion template that is timing out but the cfquery connection to the database. There is a timeout attribute for the cfquery tag. However apparently it is not reliable a better option is to configure the timout in the advanced section of the datasource within the coldfusion administrator.

Charlie Arehart blogged about this feature here:
[http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2010/7/14/hidden_gem_in_cf9_admin_querytimeout](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2010/7/14/hidden%5fgem%5fin%5fcf9%5fadmin%5fquerytimeout)